# Mean of a variable after nesting the dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to find the mean of the variable `disp` in mtcars dataset after nesting it by `cyl`.  I am able to get the result after `nest_by` but not with `group_nest`. Please explain what the `rowwise` is doing it differently here.

```r
require(tidyverse)

# working
mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl                data   avg
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <dbl>
#> 1     4           [11 × 10]  105.
#> 2     6            [7 × 10]  183.
#> 3     8           [14 × 10]  353.

# not working
mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% 
  mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `avg = mean(data$disp)`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Corrupt x: no names

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   7. ├─base::mean(data$disp)
#>   8. ├─data$disp
#>   9. ├─vctrs:::`$.vctrs_list_of`(data, disp)
#>  10. └─base::.handleSimpleError(`<fn>`, "Corrupt x: no names", base::quote(NULL))
#>  11.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  12.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

`rowwise` changes the behavior of subsequent verbs, namely instead of operating on an entire column they will now operate only on values in a given row.

This works because the `data` in mutate refers to a single dataframe (due to rowwise provided by `nest_by`)

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#> # Rowwise:  cyl
#>     cyl                data   avg
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <dbl>
#> 1     4           [11 × 10]  105.
#> 2     6            [7 × 10]  183.
#> 3     8           [14 × 10]  353.
```

This will not work because `data` refers to a list of dataframes, and `disp` is not a name in that list

```r
mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>%  mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#> Error in `mutate()`:
#> ! Problem while computing `avg = mean(data$disp)`.
#> Caused by error:
#> ! Corrupt x: no names

#> Backtrace:
#>      ▆
#>   1. ├─mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   2. ├─dplyr::mutate(., avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   3. ├─dplyr:::mutate.data.frame(., avg = mean(data$disp))
#>   4. │ └─dplyr:::mutate_cols(.data, dplyr_quosures(...), caller_env = caller_env())
#>   5. │   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
#>   6. │   └─mask$eval_all_mutate(quo)
#>   7. ├─base::mean(data$disp)
#>   8. ├─data$disp
#>   9. ├─vctrs:::`$.vctrs_list_of`(data, disp)
#>  10. └─base::.handleSimpleError(`<fn>`, "Corrupt x: no names", base::quote(NULL))
#>  11.   └─dplyr (local) h(simpleError(msg, call))
#>  12.     └─rlang::abort(...)
```

You may obtain an equivalent calculation by e.g. mapping over the list of dataframes, to apply a function to each dataframe in the list

```r
mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.x$disp)))

#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>     cyl                data   avg
#>   <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <dbl>
#> 1     4           [11 × 10]  105.
#> 2     6            [7 × 10]  183.
#> 3     8           [14 × 10]  353.
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: is there any other way we can achieve this result? using ```summarise``` after nesting?

Comment: You could substitute `summarize` for `mutate` in the working `group_nest` example above, and it would return `avg` as expected.

`mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% summarize(avg = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.x$disp)))`

Though this doesn't fundamentally change how the result is being calculated.

Answer (score 2):

We could use `map` to loop over the `list` as there is no rowwise grouping with `group_nest`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
mtcars %>%
    group_nest(cyl) %>% 
     mutate(avg = map_dbl(data, ~ mean(.x$disp)))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 3
    cyl                data   avg
  <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <dbl>
1     4           [11 × 10]  105.
2     6            [7 × 10]  183.
3     8           [14 × 10]  353.
```

According to `?group_nest`

> The primary use case for group_nest() is with already grouped data frames, typically a result of group_by().

where as with `?nest_by`

> nest_by() is closely related to group_by(). However, instead of storing the group structure in the metadata, it is made explicit in the data, **giving each group key a single row** along with a list-column of data frames that contain all the other data.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which is looking for an explanation of the differing behaviours.

Answer (score 1):

```r
> library(pacman)
> p_load(tidyverse)
> # working
> mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% class()
[1] "rowwise_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> mtcars %>% nest_by(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
# A tibble: 3 × 3
# Rowwise:  cyl
    cyl                data   avg
  <dbl> <list<tibble[,10]>> <dbl>
1     4           [11 × 10]  105.
2     6            [7 × 10]  183.
3     8           [14 × 10]  353.
> # not working
> mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% class()
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
> mtcars %>% group_nest(cyl) %>% mutate(avg = mean(data$disp))
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `avg = mean(data$disp)`.
Caused by error:
! Corrupt x: no names
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

The `nest_by` call yields a `rowwise_df` which is amenable to the next step in the pipe, whereas `group_nest` yields a plain old `tbl_df`, hence the difference

Comment: Could you specify that `nest_by(.data, ...)` returns a tibble that's grouped by `...`, whereas `group_nest()` does not? I think that's the simplest way of explaining the difference, but I don't want to submit another answer.

Comment: You could include this line from the help vignette: "nest_by() returns a rowwise data frame, which makes operations on the grouped data particularly elegant. See vignette("rowwise") for more details."